# Como posso pegar uma variável privada em uma outra classe no Java?

Tags: java

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a como eu posso pegar uma **variável private** em outra classe. Estou querendo botar todas em private para que eu tenho um melhor controle e organização.
Exemplo:

```
Class Inicio

Private int Numero = 0;
```

---

```
Class Final
  //Quero pegar a variável privada da classe Inicio nesta classe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta mais curta e preguiçosa é, você cria um método público `getNumero()` na classe `Inicio` que retorna o número privado, e chama esse método na classe `Final`. Mas isso está errado.

Em orientação a objetos, a interface pública de uma classe (isto é, seus métodos públicos) é separada de sua implementação interna (variáveis privadas). Em outras palavras, a variável `numero` é um detalhe de implementação e não deve ser exposta via método público se isso não fizer sentido para o uso que você quer fazer da classe. Um objeto Inicio só deve expor o número se isso for necessário do lado de fora da classe Inicio.

Agora se você só precisa perguntar a Inicio se o número é maior que 10, então você cria um método `public boolean númeroEhMaiorQueDez() { return numero > 10; }` e faz essa pergunta ao objeto. Em outras palavras, não existe uma relação de 1 pra 1 entre as variáveis e os métodos públicos do objeto, vai depender do que você precisa que o objeto faça, que depende do que ele representa e (indiretamente) do que ele contém.

Comment: Muito Obrigado me ajudou muito, estava prescisando disso, porque um amigo meu ultiliza private em todas as suas variáveis, e eu fiquei se perguntando se isso estava certo! Eu também tenho outra dúvida! Que é quando eu posso ultilizar o Static? Se poder me responder via coméntários eu agradeço muito! Obrigado novamente pela ajuda!

Comment: Usar private nas variáveis não está errado, errado é publicar essas variáveis que representam uma implementação interna do objeto (escondida de quem chama o objeto) através de métodos públicos getNumero() sem ver se isso realmente faz sentido.

Comment: Static: respondi lá na sua pergunta sobre static.

Comment: Obrigado +1 Vez!